# Java. Android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Всем привет, я немного знаю питон, и в нём можно сделать так чтобы скрипт открыл браузер, есть модуль Webbrouser, так вот есть ли такой модуль в Java? простите если что-то не так, я 3 дня учу джаву в android studio, всё с интернета схватываю, можете ли вы обьяснить как для чайника, который ничего в этом не шарит

Comment: для чайников, которые ничего не шарят, есть куча туториалов и учебников.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте этот код в ваш .class файл допустим так:

```
public void linkClick (View view) {
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://developer.android.com"));
                startActivity(intent);
}
```

в коде вашего layout добавьте к элементу событие onclick и в нем укажите:

```
android:onClick="linkClick"
```